# How to call $scope.$apply() using "controller as" syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to limit my use of `$scope` in my controllers as much as possible and replace it with the `Controller as` syntax.

My current problem is that i'm not sure how to call `$scope.$apply()` in my controller without using `$scope`.

Edit: I am using TypeScript 1.4 in conjunction with angular

I have this function

```js
setWordLists() {
  this.fetchInProgress = true;
  var campaignId = this.campaignFactory.currentId();
  var videoId = this.videoFactory.currentId();

  if (!campaignId || !videoId) {
    return;
  }

  this.wordsToTrackFactory.doGetWordsToTrackModel(campaignId, videoId)
  .then((response) => {
    this.fetchInProgress = false;
    this.wordList = (response) ? response.data.WordList : [];
    this.notUsedWordList = (response) ? response.data.NotUsedWords : [];
  });
}
```

being called from

```js
$scope.$on("video-switch",() => {
           this.setWordLists();
});
```

And it's (the arrays `wordList` and `notUsedWordList`) 
is not being updated in my view:

```html
<div class="wordListWellWrapper row" ng-repeat="words in wordTrack.wordList">
  <div class="col-md-5 wordListWell form-control" ng-class="(words.IsPositive)? 'posWordWell': 'negWordWell' ">
    <strong class="wordListWord">{{words.Word}}</strong>
    <div class="wordListIcon">
      <div class="whiteFaceIcon" ng-class="(words.IsPositive)? 'happyWhiteIcon': 'sadWhiteIcon' "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon" ng-click="wordTrack.removeWord(words.Word)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Along the same lines of `$apply`, is there another way of calling `$scope.$on` using `Controller as`?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to use `$scope` (or `$rootScope`) for both `$apply` and `$on`.

Comment: under 99% of all situations, you only need to call `$scope.$apply()` when you operate on the dom directly without angular's knowledge.  Unfortunately, many people resort to `$scope.$apply()` as a "fix-all" when something doesn't work, but usually the better thing to do is correct the code so that angular is aware of what is happening.

Comment: @Andrew, do you see anything in my code that would point to something broken or poorly written that could solve my problem?

Comment: your code doesn't really show where the `$scope.$on()` function is at in the controller, so perhaps we take a bit closer look at the controller code?

Comment: If you code isn't working you should post it as another question, as you have already asked about something else here. People will be confused otherwise :)

Comment: from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices, Only use  .$broadcast() ,  .$emit()  and  .$on()  for atomic events.  I suspect that you can restructure the controller to eliminate the need for .$on()

Comment: Hmm, right now i'm broadcasting from a single factory to all my controllers (only 8 of them right now) and all of my controllers need to react to this message. How would I be able to emulate this effect using some other way?

Comment: are all 8 controllers on the screen at the same time? that would be atomic.  If not, then probably wrapping the event in a $timeout and updating a variable is probably more appropriate.  of course, seeing a bit more of your architecture would be in order, to be more clear.

Comment: Yes, they are all on there at the same time. I will be branching this off to another question soon.

Comment: also, this is a great read: http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

Comment: This question is now branched.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013630/why-are-changes-in-my-arrays-in-my-controller-not-being-reflected-in-my-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question at hand here, you can use `$scope()` methods in a controller when using the controller-as syntax, as long as you pass `$scope` as a parameter to the function.  However, one of the main benefits of using the controller-as syntax is not using `$scope`, which creates a quandary.

As was discussed in the comments, a new question will be formulated by the poster to review the specific code requiring `$scope` in the first place, with some recommendations for re-structuring if possible.